# Checking SD card health data, if available

Tags: sd-card, health-monitoring

I would love to know if a SD card provides something similar to "SMART" information, like harddisks and SSDs.

I am interested in checking health information of the SD card in a Raspberry PI, for preventive replacement. My write needs are quite high and physical access to the device is complicated and it needs to be planned in advance.

I might write a device driver for this if there is information out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 4.20 of the SD Specification, there are currently no device health monitoring features. The [JEDEC eMMC 5.0 spec](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd84-b51) added device health indicators in Sept 2013 and version [6.0 of the SD spec](http://www.infoinc.com/SDA_Member/0215.html) is supposed to follow by the end of the year.

That said, it's typically several months before the first devices supporting the new spec comes out and even longer before it has majority market share.

Comment: I am wondering if you could provide some URLs to support your comment. Thanks!.

Comment: @jcea Unfortunately the SD spec is only available for [SD Card Association](https://www.sdcard.org/index.html) members, so I can prove they're not there. But I linked to a news release that they're coming.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the references. I hope I can do "smart" or similar on future SD cards.

Comment: As this answer is from 2015: Is there an update in the meantime how to check SD card health? This is one of the few posts I found when searching.

Comment: The motion to add a health report failed to gain support and was not added to the specification.